# MySQL scheduling an event

Tags: mysql

I tried with this syntax but it never transferred the data.

```
CREATE EVENT event_test1 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2010-09-02 15:19:25' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
    insert into schema2.table1 (ID) select ID from schema1.table1 Limit 1000
```

I don't see the o/p in the table1 of schema2, what did i miss?

Comment: Even i tried this line

 insert into schema2.table1 (ID) select schema1.table1.ID from schema1.table1 Limit 1000; but still nothing is getting transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn events on?

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 'ON';
```

Also, the SHOW EVENTS command will show you if the event is there and running.